# bash while loop threading

Tags: multithreading, bash, shell, while-loop

i have a while loop reading lines from a `$hosts`

```
while read line
do
    ip=$line
    check
done < $hosts
```

my question is can I use some way to speed this up or run the check on 10 hosts at a time and each check is on a different IP and finish when all IP in `$host` have been checked?
Thanks

Comment: To be completely correct, Bash has no access to *threading.* A background job runs a separate *process,* not in a thread. So strictly speaking, this is multiprocessing, not multithreading.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can send tasks to the background by `&`
If you intend to wait for all of them to finish you can use the `wait` command:

```
process_to_background &
echo Processing ...
wait
echo Done
```

You can get the `pid` of the given task started in the background if you want to wait for one (or few) specific tasks.

```
important_process_to_background &
important_pid=$!
while i in {1..10}; do
    less_important_process_to_background $i &
done

wait $important_pid
echo Important task finished

wait
echo All tasks finished
```

On note though: the background processes can mess up the output as they will run asynchronously. You might want to use a named pipe to collect the output from them.

**edit**

As asked in the comments there might be a need for limiting the background processes forked. In this case you can keep track of how many background processes you've started and communicate with them through a named pipe.

```
mkfifo tmp # creating named pipe

counter=0
while read ip
do
  if [ $counter -lt 10 ]; then # we are under the limit
    { check $ip; echo 'done' > tmp; } &
    let $[counter++];
  else
    read x < tmp # waiting for a process to finish
    { check $ip; echo 'done' > tmp; } &
  fi
done
cat /tmp > /dev/null # let all the background processes end

rm tmp # remove fifo
```

Comment: Will this cycle through every host in $hosts? Even if there is more than 10? I don't want to start any more than 10 processes it could start taking up too much resources.

Comment: This is just an example how you can use background processes and how you can wait for them. If you want to specify the maximum number of threads that sounds like a thread pool. For that I add an example, however it might not be the best implementation

Comment: When does counter get decremented?

Comment: It gets decremented each time it reads a line. Echo which also prints new line.

Comment: @Interlated, we never decrement the counter: the counter is used to initialise a "pool" of background processes limited in number, then we create a new background process if still needed whenever a previously started background process finishes

Answer (score 6):

You can start multiple processes, each calling the function `check` and wait for them to finish.

```
while read line 
do 
  ip=$line
  check &
done < $hosts
wait # wait for all child processes to finish
```

Whether this increases the *speed* depends on available processors and the function `check`'s implementation. You have to ensure there's no data dependency in `check` between iterations.

Answer (score 5):

Use [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```bash
parallel check ::: $hosts
```